# Are bounded functions whose f(a)>0, for a fixed a, a open set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $B(X, R))$  be the metric space of bounded functions $f:X \rightarrow R$ (X metric) and the subset $A_a\dot{=}\{f_a \in B(X,R):f(a)>0, a\in X \ \ fixed\}$. I have to verify wether $A_a$ is an open set or not. I`ve got an intuiton saying it is indeed but I couldn`t work it out much.

$Sketch:$ I thought about the prove in these way: $A_a$ is bounded iff there existis such a g in a open ball centered in $f_a$ and also that g(a)>0. I tried working these idea from inequalities of the distances (which come from de supremum of f(x) in X). Couldn`t land in anything... Also, I thought about assuming that g(a)>0 and using that to prove that there is such a $\epsilon$ which makes possible having a g into the open ball $B(f_a,\epsilon)$

Comment: What is the metric on $B(X,R)$?

Comment: $d(f,g)\dot{=} sup\{ |f(x)-g(x)|: x\in X \} $

Answer (score 2):

**Idea:**
Is the mapping $\Phi\colon B(X,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$\Phi(g) = g(a)$$
continuous? If so, what is $\Phi^{-1}((0,\infty))$?

Comment: I`ve proved once that the discontinuous functions form a open set, tried to extract some Ideas from there but nothing was helpful. I will try to work your idea, let me just understand a lit bit further: u mean that i should use the fact that open sets are invariant under homeomorphisms ?

Comment: Showing that $\Phi$ is continuous should be a matter of a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $f \in B(X,\mathbb{R})$. Then

$B_{f(a)/2}(f) = \{ g \in B(X,\mathbb{R})\ :\ \sup_{x \in X}|f(x) - g(x)| < f(a)/2 \}$. (This is the ball of radius $f(a)/2$ about $f$)

And if $g \in B_{f(a)/2}(f)$, then $\sup_{x \in X}|f(x) - g(x)| < f(a)/2$, and in particular $|g(a) - f(a)| < f(a)/2$, which implies that $g(a) > f(a) - f(a)/2 = f(a)/2 > 0$. And so $g \in A_a$.

This shows that $B_{f(a)/2}(f) \subset A_a$, which means that $A_a$ is open.

Alternatively you could prove the complement is closed quite easily. Take a convergent sequence $f_n$ in the complement of $A_a$, say $f_n \to f$. Certainly $f_n$ converges pointwise and $f_n(a) \leq 0$, so $f(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(a) \leq 0$, which shows that $f \notin A_a$.

Comment: Thanks! I liked a lot the alternative way! Is it possible only because $B(X, R)$ is metric?